# Passing PHP to jQuery append function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

I would like to pass some PHP into my jQuery append functions. I know I can't pass PHP directly, so I was trying to make the PHP into a variable and then call the variable within the jQuery instead. Is this possible?

Here's what I have so far(not working):

```
function appendElements() {
var template_dir = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>";
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1100px)").matches) {
jQuery("#container").append("\
    <div id='BG' class='bg_images' data-stellar-ratio='.5'>\
        <img src='"+template_dir+"/assets/scroll/site/bg_desktop.png'/>\
    </div>\
    ");
}
```

Comment: It is indeed possible, **if** the javascript code goes thru the PHP parser.

Comment: and if what adeneo said doesn't make sense, the PHP parser would be any file served as php. This looks like wordpress so you could just put that in a script tag in the header.php file. js files would not parse that.

Comment: You would also need to echo the value of `bloginfo`: `var template_dir = "<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>";` or using PHP's short tags: `var template_dir = "<?=bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>";`

Comment: @Rob M. wp's bloginfo function will echo automatically. No need for echo unless he is using get_bloginfo() - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so what do I have to change about the code to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<script> var template_dir = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>"; </script>` in between your `<head></head>` tags.

Then run your function as you normally would:

```
function appendElements() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1100px)").matches) {
        jQuery("#container").append("\
            <div id='BG' class='bg_images' data-stellar-ratio='.5'>\
                <img src='"+template_dir+"/assets/scroll/site/bg_desktop.png'/>\
            </div>\
        ");
    }
}
```